# How to use all features of widgetVar in primefaces ?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want ondouble click the size of input text will increase and when it is not on focus it will gain its original width.

```
    <p:inputText widgetVar="user" 
    doubleclick="PF('user').style.width = '300px'"
    oncomplete="PF('user').style.width = '175px'"/>
```

like this I want to dynamically add style classes to it ? If any one have any link where complete reference of how to use widgetVar is given please give me. Thanks.

Comment: First result in Google: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/ In the end, to do what you need to do, you just need to get the JQuery object using `getJQ()` and manipulate that.

Comment: `widgetVar.getJQ().addClass('whateverClass')`

Comment: Very useful It works totally well.  @Robby Cornelissen